# I do not see the hello world command in command pallete

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So the [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) to developing visual studio code extensions says to hit `F5` and then command palette which is where I should see the `hello world` command given by this default code for extension. This is the [repository](https://github.com/ArchKoder/bulkdatahelper) for the default code generated by following the tutorial. I do not see the command and I require some help as to troubleshoot. Let me know if any additional info is required.

Comment: Instead of rushing to your own, get started from the official ones, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples

Comment: I see @LexLi   but this is entirely the code generated by `yo` module. If I do start with some other then how do I find one which is written in JavaScript and not type script

Comment: 1. It is not clear whether the `yo code` bits are up-to-date. 2. Via that GitHub repo you can actually connect to the Microsoft team behind extension API.

Comment: I see @LexLi   I can start from here  'https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/helloworld-minimal-sample'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why No Matching Commands when I init my first vscode extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74149764/why-no-matching-commands-when-i-init-my-first-vscode-extension)

Comment: I can not confirm the solution to that exact problem but I am convinced that vscode version was problem since I was using 6 months older portable version at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that the extensions required VsCode 1.74. Check the Log(Window) in the 'Extension Development Host`.

Answer (score 1):

During development the extension will only live in the "guest" window that appears when you start debugging - this is where you should be looking for the contributed command (or anything else done by the extension).

The extension will appear in your VSCode instance if you install it - either by packaging it and installing it locally or by publishing it to the Extension Marketplace and then installing it from there.

Edit: I pulled your repo and ran the extension. Everything is working as expected. You're probably missing something.

Comment: Hitting `F5` does give me another window named 'Extension Development Host` which is where I am trying to find `Hello Word` command. Is that not the correct window?

Comment: "Extension Development Host" is the window you should be looking at, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but fixed it by updating VSCode. I'm on Ubuntu and have VSCode installed via snap. I had to make sure all VSCode processes were closed then ran the command `snap refresh code`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when I go to help there I see restart to update. I just clicked on that tab and vs code restarted. After that I'm able to see the Hello World in command palette.

So try updating your VS Code or check help tab is there any updation required.