# Why No Matching Commands when I init my first vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I init my first vscode extension following [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension).

Here is my steps:

1. npm install -g yo generator-code
2. yo code

And here is the package.json generated:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "displayName": "helloworld",
  "description": "description helloworld",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.72.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:helloworld.helloWorld"
  ],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "helloworld.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/glob": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.72.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.1",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.5",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

When I press H5 to debug, I got no command matched here:
[image]

I was stuck here for a while, where is my command??

Comment: What if you search for `hello world` with the space?

Comment: You are not the first to ask this week, so I assume `yo code` is broken, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143522/i-do-not-see-the-hello-world-command-in-command-pallete

Comment: I tried every combination of "hello world", uppercase, lowercase, white space included...None of those works

Comment: @Lex Li I pulled the repo from microsoft, it works

Answer (score 12):

I've encountered this just now as well. Make sure that `engines.vscode` in `package.json` matches the version of vscode you are running:

```
"engines": {
  "vscode": "^1.73.0"
},
```

I guess the generator will use the latest version available, but you might not have upgraded yet. That was the case for me.

Comment: +1 -- I just tried to run the Hello World extension and the package.json setting was "vscode": "^1.79.0" while my actual installed version of VS Code was 1.78.2. The Hello World extension wouldn't show up in the Extension Development Host until I knocked the the version back to "vscode": "^1.78.0". Thanks, @tacospice !